# Could not cast value of type 'UIViewController'

Tags: ios, swift, casting, lldb, bwwalkthrough

I am trying to implement BWWalkthrough in my project.  However I get an error stating

```
Unknown class _TtC20BWWalkthroughExample27BWWalkthroughViewController in Interface Builder file.
Could not cast value of type 'UIViewController' (0x195bca580) to 'AppName.BWWalkthroughViewController' (0x10042c3a0).
(lldb)
```

It is pointing at the below code

```
let walkthrough = stb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("walk") as! BWWalkthroughViewController
```

I don't know why this is happening. Any help would be appreciated.

Also feel free to ask for more code from my project.

Comment: did you set the class of the custom view controller explicitly to `BWWalkthroughViewController` in Interface Builder?

Comment: Swift does not support name de-mangiing yet so you get: `_TtC20BWWalkthroughExample27BWWalkthroughViewController`, this is similar to C++ name mangling but that was addressed for error messages decades ago.

Comment: For more info on the names that look like `_TtC20BWWalkthroughExample27BWWalkthroughViewController`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062957/swift-objective-c-runtime-class-naming

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your storyboard doesn't seem to be linked to a `BWWalkthroughViewController`. Find where the view controller should be a `BWWalkthroughViewController`, and check if it is one.

Answer (score 6):

I have same issue.

I can fix to set BWWalkthroughViewController, not BWWalkthroughPageViewController in my walthrough storyboard.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue

Unknown class WelcomeViewController in Interface Builder file. Could not cast value of type 'UIViewController' (0x7fff898d1f50) to 'SimpleLoginApp.WelcomeViewController' (0x108864c48).

Was able to resolve it by following these steps:

1. Open storyboard file
2. Select the View Controller that is not being identified.
3. Open Attribute Inspector and check if the "Module" text field is mapped with the appropriate app name.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the IB make sure that you set the class of the master view controller into BWWalkthroughViewController, as well as the module BWWalkthrough. See the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjKaa.png) . I just ran into this problem myself, easy step to forget sometimes.

Answer (score -1):

Please follow these steps to fix your issues.

1. Create BWWalkthroughViewController ViewController Class.
2. Main StoryBoard
3. BWWalkthroughViewController
4. Show Identity Inspector.
5. Add BWWalkthroughViewController
6. Check again